# How to make objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

How can I do this in javascript? (Adding getters and setters properly)

```
public class User {

    private UUID uuid;
    private String nickName;
    private double coins;
    private int level;
    private float exp;

    public User(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.nickName = null;
        this.coins = 0D;
        this.level = 1;
        this.exp = 0F;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get or you can just use JS classes.

Comment: [Class syntax](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) is well documented. [JS tutorials](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) are available throughout the Internet. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212). What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you don't need to create first a class to create an object. A Javascript object is an associative array that can contain also functions:

```js
// example of JavaScript object
const user = {
   uuid: "user-identifier",
   nickname: null,
   // ...
}
```

Of course you can define a function that returns an object. You can think at that function as a constructor if you want, but it is just a function that returns an object. Function closures allow you to define private variables.

```js
function User (uuid) {
   let coins = 0;  // Visible only inside this function
   return {
      uuid: uuid,
      nickname: nickname,
      getCoins: function () { return coins }
   }
}
```

Inheritance is prototypal in Javascript: you take an object and you create a new object that inherits all its properties.

```js
const parentObject = {/*key-value-pairs*/};
const childObject = Object.create(parentObject);
```

JavaScript has a [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator that makes it easier to handle inheritance and makes a function look like a class.

Recently also a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) statement has been added to JavaScript but it is just sintactic shugar for the prototype pattern.

With that in mind, I suggest you read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) for a thorough introduction to JavaScript objects.

Comment: *"A Javascript object is an associative array"* ... nope ... there is nothing like that in JS ... objects are merely *bags of key value pairs*.

Comment: "*but it is just sintactic[syntactic] shugar[sugar]*" ... also not correct ... there is more to it than just the nice syntax. With ES6 classes one e.g. gets a bullet proof sub typing system even for built in objects. Something one could never achieve with just `function` and `prototype`.